# PHP includes work fine in development under EasyPHP, but not when uploaded to host

Tags: php, html

I've built a very simple website using PHP Includes to display the footer and sidebar, these PHP includes work when I'm on my computer and view them using EasyPHP, however when I come to upload the site and view it I get the following error displayed on page:

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: open_basedir restriction in effect.
File(/usr/local/apache/htdocs/includes/sidebar.php) is not within the allowed path(s):
(/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/a5562725/public_html/index.php on line 26
```

[Here's the site,](http://marcuslywood.co.uk) hosted for free on 000webhost.

Here's an example of an include on index.php, used to display the sidebar inside my "includes" folder:

```
    <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/sidebar.php"; ?>
```

I'm using the DOCUMENT_ROOT instead of a normal include because some pages are embedded in deeper directories, and the includes will become dead links.

Comment: It is probably permissions problem. Make sure the apache user is able to open the sidebar.php. If unsure, make the /includes/sidebar.php to be with 755 permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing since it will be shared hosting it may be set to you're webroot...

So simply include using:

```
<?php include "/includes/sidebar.php"; ?>
```

To expand on that a bit... Hosting Providers usually set open_basedir for security reasons (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I now get the following error: 

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/includes/sidebar.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/a5562725/public_html/index.php on line 26

You can view it for yourself on http://marcuslywood.co.uk/

Comment: OK try <?php include "includes/sidebar.php"; ?>

Comment: Thanks! That works for top-level pages, however, as stated in the question, I have some files in lower down directories that need these includes too, I assume I should just use the normal "../" before the path to go up a directory, just like in HTML and CSS? 

Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic, can't believe it was that simple haha! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This always happens, as soon as I ask the question I find the solution!

Yes, the problem was to do with shared hosting it seems, I had to point to my home root of my host for it to work, for 000webhost users, you can find this on the right hand side of your control panel.

My includes now look like this:

```
<?php include('/home/a********/public_html/includes/sidebar.php'); ?>
```

Where the *s are your home root.

Comment: You are better off using Brian's suggestion as you then won't need to keep changing this path based on where you deploy your code.